# Please help me to continue this function, this is to fetch data from web service and parse the xml response

Tags: c#-4.0

```
string XML = "http://uat.rgfs.com.ph/DMPI/DMPI_client.php?sc=DMPIMYHR&p=12a048a23aa417f48a3a6ccd7395b9ac&tc=REPSMASPP&cc=DMPISPP&en=91118-7510006";
string returnXML;

HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(XML);
httpRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)";

using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
    returnXML = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

}
return returnXML;
```

Comment: What do you want to parse? What do you want the output to be?

Comment: I want to have xml response then parse them to able able to save to variables and post on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Load you response object into xml document.
Check this : http://forums.asp.net/t/1957761.aspx?Read+XML+in+C+

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?